# Android Tweet message is not Showing on Twitter Wall

Tags: android, twitter

i know  i have aske dthis question,but i am not getting any satisfaction solution till yet.,i registered in twitter for getting consumer key,and secret key.,i am getting login ,but when i update any message on twitter it show sme message has been updated,but when i am checkinh in my twitterid.,i am not getting any message.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {// Constants
  static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ""; // place your cosumer key here
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ""; // place your consumer secret here

// Preference Constants
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String oauth_token = "";
static final String oauth_token_secret = "";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "";

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "";

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "oauth_autherize";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

// Login button
private   Button btnLoginTwitter;
// Update status button
private   Button btnUpdateStatus;
// Logout button
private  Button btnLogoutTwitter;
// EditText for update
private    EditText txtUpdate;
// lbl update
private   TextView lblUpdate;
private  TextView lblUserName;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Twitter
private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;
private AccessToken accessToken;

// Shared Preferences
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

// Internet Connection detector
private ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if twitter keys are set
    if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // All UI elements
    btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
    btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
    btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
    txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
    lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
    lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);
    btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            loginToTwitter();
        }
    });

    btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();
            new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);

        } 

    });
    btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function
            logoutFromTwitter();
        }
    });

    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            final String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            // Get the access token
                            MainActivity.this.accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                    requestToken, verifier);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                e.putString(oauth_token, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(oauth_token_secret,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                // Hide login button
                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Show Update Twitter
                lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Getting user details from twitter
                // For now i am getting his name only
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();

                // Displaying in xml ui
                lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter4j.conf.Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();


        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    requestToken = twitter
                            .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();         
    } else {
        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private int statusId;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token 
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(oauth_token,"");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(oauth_token_secret, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);

            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}

private void logoutFromTwitter() {
    // Clear the shared preferences
    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    e.remove(oauth_token);
    e.remove(oauth_token_secret);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    e.commit();

    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUserName.setText("");
    lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
    // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
    return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

}
here i am getting this image.,when i get logedin..[image]

Comment: SocialAuth Android is an Android version of popular SocialAuth Java library. Now you do not need to integrate multiple SDKs if you want to integrate your application with multiple social networks. You just need to add few lines of code after integrating the SocialAuth Android library in your app. Go to this [socialauth-android](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr). One of the best approach to integrate all social media

Comment: @MD sir i used socialauth library..,but my message is not posting..

Comment: Where do u put your Keys?

Comment: @MD sir i am putting my keys here. static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ""; // place your cosumer key here
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ""; // place your consumer secret here

Comment: You must put this keys into one file into Assets properties.txt file.

Comment: @MD can you give me anyexample,and where i put my oauth_token and oauth_token_secret key

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46572/discussion-between-m-d-and-rajshree)

Comment: wait for a while sending u full steps

Comment: So finally it's working

Comment: @MD yes sir..,i want to give ranking,on your answer..,how i do thta??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to add the `OAuth consumer keys` and `secrets` into `Assets` in `oauth_consumer.properties file`, that you can get by registering your application with twitter. They have bundled keys so that you can test quickly, but it is strongly recommended that you change these keys. First, it is a security issue for your application and secondly sometimes our keys give errors because too many developers are testing.

`SocialAuth` Android is an Android version of popular `SocialAuth Java library`. Now you do not need to integrate multiple `SDKs` if you want to integrate your application with multiple social networks. You just need to add few lines of code after integrating the `SocialAuth` Android library in your app. Go to this socialauth-android. One of the best approach to integrate all social media.

Go to this link for better understanding [socialauth-android](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/wiki/Getting-Started) .also, code available in [Github](https://github.com/3pillarlabs)

Comment: sir i am working on foursqure..,i used cod eof github..,before some days it was working..,but now when i am using it again it is giving e errro

Comment: @rajshree tell me what is u r problem? do u have upload any question in Stacky?

Comment: sir my problem is that i am getting no response ..from server when i am using my clientid and secret